# Assembly Language Programming

Tags: assembly

i just started learning Assembly programming for operating system development i refer the link

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev0.html
and have problem with what is difference between DOS Assembly and Linux Assembly what are they?
Does it mean assembly programming in Linux and dos simply if yes then what's the differnce.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; assembly is a level below both Linux and DOS.

Comment: Different operating systems, different ABIs, and you may also be using different assemblers with different syntaxes, etc.

Comment: Your link is about [tag:c] development, not assembly per sé.

Comment: Probably he means the difference between 16-bit Intel styled real mode assembler on Dos and AT&T style 32-bit PM asm on Linux. So both syntax and memory model.

Comment: Because the link talks about C, I imagine part of the confusion may stem from different platforms using different calling conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each processor architecture tens to have its own "assembly language", and each platform (operating system, firmware, etc.) may have different system calls to handle operations for you (so things like initiating IO, etc.).

As such, there's no such thing as "DOS Assembly" or "Linux Assembly", but instead combinations like "x86 Assembly for DOS platform", "ARM Assembly for Linux platform", "x86 Assembly for Linux", even "68K Assmebly for Atari ST" and "68K Assembly for Commodore Amiga" - the instructions are specific to the processor, and the calls are specific to the platform.

Taking a move instruction as an example, for Intel x86 processors, it's simply `mov`; for Motorola 68K Processors, it'd be `move.l` (to move a `long`), and on ARM, it'd be `ldr`.

Comment: Sir,i am little bit confused here firstly i have to select platform for my OS development eg:i choose Linux as platform and then i will choose my processor architecture language  like X86 Assembly is this write way of saying or still i am not on correct track.If yes can you tell me how processor architecture(like intel X86,Motorola 6800 etc) affects operating system development.

Comment: If you're writing in assembler (and not a highler level language, like C, C++, C#, Java, Python, etc.) You choose your processor architecture **and** your platform, and then get going. If you want to be processor agnostic, you choose a higher level language, as the compiler handles most of the heavy lifting in converting to the relevant dialect of machine code, as well as providing libraries for handling abstracted methods for string handling, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir it clear's my confusion a great help

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708532/why-isnt-my-assembly-program-setting-r1-to-the-correct-value

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what assembly programming, operating systems, the assembler tool and linker and some more tool chain components are.

If you are talking about `Linux assembly` you have not understand what are you doing I believe!

The assembly language (mnemonics) are depending to the CPU. (For Linux it could be x86, arm, ppc and tons of others!)
The assembly syntax (labels, macros, ... ) are depending to the assembly tool you are using like `as` from gnu for Linux. There are hundreds of assembler tools like masm, as, ...

You have to use some toolchain components for linking/relocation/.... like ld from gnu.

There is nothing like `DOS assembly` or `Linux assembly` in the real world!

Comment: May you be right can anyone give reference clear this concepts..i am confused with these the" assembler tool and linker and some more tool chain components are". terms plz help me out.

Comment: Sorry, you want to program. So I think youhave to start on ONE plattform and select your tools you are need. If you have questions regarding a complete toolchain for dedicated cpu-architecture/OS and maybe distribution specifics, feel free to ask again. But nobody want to describe the complete toolchain here I believe! Please read beginners book or some articles in the web.

Answer (score 1):

So think of C the programming language, there is the C programming language and there are places it is used.  You can write windows programs with C and Linux programs with C and so on.  Without going into tangents lest assume that the compilers you are using on these various platforms support the same C language based on some standard, and certainly whatever your knowledge of C is translates.

BUT the difference between a Windows C program and a Linux C program is when you get into the system calls, basically when you ask the operating system to do something like draw a window on the desktop.  Obviously the operating systems are different and those calls are different, there is a C library for fopen/fclose for example but what you dont see there is buried in the C library is more C code that someone else wrote that makes operating specific calls, the linux calls can be and often are different than the windows calls.

Now replace everything I said above with some other language, say x86 assembly language for example.

Now we know that although C compilers strive to conform to a standard for the language that standard contains many "implementation defined" areas, which allow for compilers to vary and the user experience to vary independent of the operating system, but within the language.  assembly language is much much worse than that in that the only real definition is the machine code.  The chip vendors attempt to define the language in their instruction set reference manuals which often define both the machine code and the assembly language, and that defined assembly language matches the assembler that they have created for that processor or have contracted someone to create.  Then there is gnu, those folks like to do anything but conform with the established assembly language defined by the processor vendor and their tool.  In the x86 case you have the problem of intel syntax (the original syntax as defined by intel and their tools and supported by microsofts tools as well) then there was AT&T syntax with the operands backward, and that was adopted by the gnu tools (among other annoyances).  Further problems are that x86 has evolved from a 16/8 bit processor to 32 to 64 and along the way there have been added instructions and depending on what system you are on you can and cant do things because of what processor mode you are in.  Then of course the operating system differences for system calls.

x86 is one of the worst first assembly languages to learn, if you have to do this for a class so be it but if you want to understand assembly language, vs system calls, vs what compilers produce, and the operating system things, start elsewhere like arm.  Once you learn one system the translation to another is easy, and running on a simulator will lead to far less failure than on hardware so using the I have this hardware excuse is just a lack of understanding.  With time, if you succeed, you will understand what I am saying.  msp430/pdp11 are excellent first instruction sets, then maybe arm after that and you can get into system calls on arm and then any other instruction set is just a matter of syntax.  Starting with more sane instruction sets and moving to the less sane can be done in hours or days, going in a different order may take weeks or months or just lead to failure.  With a simulator with good visibility you can dig out of a lot of beginner traps.  hardware doesnt give that visibility even with a debugger.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir it clear's my confusion a great help

Answer (score 1):

DOS assembly versus Linux assembly. Classic DOS is a 16 real mode operating system, while Linux is 32 bit or 64 bit protected mode operating system where applications run in a virtual flat address space. There are 32 bit versions of "DOS".

Perhaps the "difference" in assembly is a reference to the difference between Intel and ATT syntax. For two operand instructions, Intel syntax uses destination, source, while ATT syntax uses source, destination. ATT syntax prefixes register references with "%", and suffixes instructions with a letter to indicate if the operand is 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, or 64 bit. Intel syntax doesn't prefix register instructions, and relies on the register name for operand size (al, ax, eax, rax), or a prefix on the address operand such as "byte ptr", ... "qword ptr", for an instruction that involves an immediate value with a memory operand. Some (or most?) Linux assemblers use ATT syntax, while Microsoft and Intel assemblers use Intel syntax.

The article is also wrong about C not being able to produce a flat binary image. This is a function of the tool set. Old Microsoft tool sets included the utility "exe2bin" which would produce a flat binary file, or if the "model" was "tiny", a flat binary image called a .COM file was created.